# All language package not available in magento connect

Tags: magento-1.9, language, language-package

I want to add a new language in my site frontend `Nepali` (Country Nepal). There will be two languages `Nepali` & `English` options in frontend. So as i explored about adding i can find the simple steps,

```
- Go to System > Magento Connect > Magento Connect Manager
- Install your desired language package
```

The problem is there isn't a language package available for this particular language so, how can i make one or overwrite existing one ? How is it possible ?

Answer (score 1):

There is a mini tutorial [here](http://www.demacmedia.com/magento-commerce/mini-tutorial-creating-a-custom-locale-in-magento/). Follow those steps to create your own locale. There are 2 options to handle this (as stated in the tutorial):

1) Rewriting Mage_Core_Model_Locale_Config and other classes (such as the Zend lib) to include our new locale (not recommended as it’s so much work)

or

2) Define your own custom language to “piggyback” on another locale and use their code for your custom language pack.

Comment: Ok, the second option looks much handy. How is store view `code` related with `locale` folder ?

Comment: It is not. You select a locale for each store using the admin, where the language code is already defined. For example, spanish is es, english is en, not sure about Nepali.